# How to populate select list from another one on runtime?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I tried to populate a list of cities based on countries list
using  **jscript** to create both lists  and **json** as a data file 
and **jquery** for listening to the change method when the user changes the selected index of countries list.

after testing it, it was working but the list of cities did not appear, but it appears inside the HTML source when I open debugging mode in Chrome.

Kindly need help to explain this issue and to fix it.

```js
var _countries =
[
  { "id": "1", "Country": "USA"},
  { "id": "2", "Country": "CANADA"},
  { "id": "3", "Country": "GERMANY"}
];

var _citeis =
[
  { "countryID": "1", "id": "1", "City": "New York" },
  { "countryID": "1", "id": "2", "City": "California" },
  { "countryID": "2", "id": "3", "City": "Toronto" },
  { "countryID": "3", "id": "4", "City": "Berlin" },
  { "countryID": "3", "id": "5", "City": "Hamburg" },
  { "countryID": "3", "id": "6", "City": "Munich" },
];
var countries = _countries;
var countriesDiv = document.getElementById("_countriesList");
var countriesselectList = document.createElement("select");
countriesselectList.id = "countriesList";
countriesDiv.appendChild(countriesselectList);
//Create and append Countries to the options
for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
    var countriesoption = document.createElement("option");
    countriesoption.value = countries[i].id;
    countriesoption.text = countries[i].Country;
    countriesselectList.appendChild(countriesoption);
}


$('#countriesList').change(function () {
    //populate Cities list
    var cities = _cities;
    var citiesDiv = document.getElementById("_citiesList");
    var citiesselectList = document.createElement("select");
    citiesselectList.id = "citieslist";
    citiesDiv.appendChild(citiesselectList);
    //Create and append Cities to the options
    for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
        {
            if (cities[i].countryID == countriesselectList.value) {
                var citiesoption = document.createElement("option");
                citiesoption.value = cities[i].id
                citiesoption.text = cities[i].City;
                citiesselectList.appendChild(citiesoption);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="_countriesList" class="col s12">
     <!-- Create Countries List Here -->
</div>
<div id="_citiesList" class="col s12">
     <!-- Create Cities List Here -->
</div>
```

UPDATE -- Result After Implement the code

```
<div id="cities_list" class="col s12">
    <!-- Cities List -->
    <div class="select-wrapper">
        <span class="caret">▼</span><input type="text" class="select-dropdown" readonly="true" data-activates="select-options-bf789281-0252-e649-5f47-1ae7002cf997" value="Dakar"><ul id="select-options-bf789281-0252-e649-5f47-1ae7002cf997" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown ">
            <li class=""><span>Dakar</span></li>
            <li class=""><span>Touba</span></li>
            <li class=""><span>Thiès</span></li>
            <li class=""><span>Rufisque</span></li>
            <li class=""><span>Ziguinchor</span></li>
            <li class=""><span>Diourbel</span></li>
            <li class=""><span>Louga</span></li>
        </ul>
        <select id="citieslist" class="initialized">
            <option value="1">Jeddah</option>
            <option value="2">Khobar</option>
            <option value="3">Madina</option>
            <option value="4">Riyadh</option>
            <option value="5">Yanbu</option>
            <option value="6">Jubail</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

---- why I have 2 lists, and the first one which appears on the page is unchangeable when I select a new country.

Comment: None of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5Dpopulate+select+list+from+another)?

Comment: If you can see it in live html something else not shown is wrong, such as a css rule hiding it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.filter()` to extract just the cities with the correct country code. I've changed the code a little to simplifying it (as you are already using jquery).

## Demo

```js
var _countries = [{
    "id": "1",
    "Country": "USA"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "Country": "CANADA"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "Country": "GERMANY"
  }
]

var _cities = [{
    "countryID": "1",
    "id": "1",
    "City": "New York"
  },
  {
    "countryID": "1",
    "id": "2",
    "City": "California"
  },
  {
    "countryID": "2",
    "id": "3",
    "City": "Toronto"
  },
  {
    "countryID": "3",
    "id": "4",
    "City": "Berlin"
  },
  {
    "countryID": "3",
    "id": "5",
    "City": "Hamburg"
  },
  {
    "countryID": "3",
    "id": "6",
    "City": "Munich"
  },
]


//Create countries list
var countries = _countries;
var countriesDiv = document.getElementById("_countriesList");
var countriesselectList = document.createElement("select");
countriesselectList.id = "countriesList";
countriesDiv.appendChild(countriesselectList);

//Create and append Countries to the options
for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
  var countriesoption = document.createElement("option");
  countriesoption.value = countries[i].id;
  countriesoption.text = countries[i].Country;
  countriesselectList.appendChild(countriesoption);
}

// As we are selecting first option by default, update city list
updateCitiesList();


// update city list on change of country
$('#countriesList').change(function() {
  updateCitiesList();
});


// Update city list function
function updateCitiesList() {


  //Get country ID from country select
  countryID = $("#_countriesList option:selected").attr("value");

  // Filter cities depending on countryID
  var cities = $(_cities).filter(function(i, n) {
    return n.countryID == parseInt(countryID);
  });

  // Clear current select options for citiesList
  $("#citieslist option").remove();

  //Create and append Cities to the options
  for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
    {

      var citiesoption = document.createElement("option");
      citiesoption.value = cities[i].id
      citiesoption.text = cities[i].City;
      $("#citieslist").append(citiesoption);

      // Show #citiesList
      $("#citieslist.hidden").removeClass("hidden");

    }
  }

}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="_countriesList" class="col s12">
  <!-- Create Countries List Here -->
</div>
<div id="_citiesList" class="col s12">
  <!-- Create Cities List Here -->
  <select id="citieslist" class="hidden">

  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: again, Hi Oliver, after applying the code with CSS the same issue happened, this time the code generates the select list but I found another <ul> with generated id like Select-option-GID and has the previous names of previous 
 selected cities, so the new result will not appear.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a typo in the CSS selector of countriesList. It should be `$('#_countriesList')`. I also spotted one more typo int the _citeis rather than _cities.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run your javascript when the document is "ready", the below should work. Also bear in mind that you will be appending a new `select` every time you change the country, I think what you are trying to do is replace the `select`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
       //Create countries list
       var countries = _countries;
       var countriesDiv = document.getElementById("_countriesList");
       var countriesselectList = document.createElement("select");
       countriesselectList.id = "countriesList";
       countriesDiv.appendChild(countriesselectList);
       //Create and append Countries to the options
       for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
           var countriesoption = document.createElement("option");
           countriesoption.value = countries[i].id;
           countriesoption.text = countries[i].Country;
           countriesselectList.appendChild(countriesoption);
       }

       $(function () {
       $('#countriesList').change(function () {
           //populate Cities list
           var cities = _cities;
           var citiesDiv = document.getElementById("_citiesList");
           var citiesselectList = document.createElement("select");
           citiesselectList.id = "citieslist";
           citiesDiv.appendChild(citiesselectList);
           //Create and append Cities to the options
           for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
               {
                   if (cities[i].countryID == countriesselectList.value) {
                       var citiesoption = document.createElement("option");
                       citiesoption.value = cities[i].id
                       citiesoption.text = cities[i].City;
                       citiesselectList.appendChild(citiesoption);
                   }
               }
           }
       });
   });

    </script>
```

Here is the documentation for the 
 [jquery's `$( document ).ready()`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: Because `$(function() {});` is a shorthand for `$( document ).ready()`

Answer (score 1):

While you tagged a Jquery and you use it .. It'll be better *for me* to use jquery on this script .. this is how can be done with jquery

```js
var _countries =
  [
    { "id": "1", "Country": "USA"},
    { "id": "2", "Country": "CANADA"},
    { "id": "3", "Country": "GERMANY"}
  ]

var _cities =
  [
    { "countryID": "1", "id": "1", "City": "New York" },
    { "countryID": "1", "id": "2", "City": "California" },
    { "countryID": "2", "id": "3", "City": "Toronto" },
    { "countryID": "3", "id": "4", "City": "Berlin" },
    { "countryID": "3", "id": "5", "City": "Hamburg" },
    { "countryID": "3", "id": "6", "City": "Munich" },
  ]
  
 $(document).ready(function(){
    // Append the countries
    // onload loop through the _countries array and append them to #countries select
    $.each(_countries ,function(i){
      $("#countries").append('<option value="'+_countries[i].id+'">'+_countries[i].Country+'</option>');
    });
    
    //Change Event
    $("#countries").on("change" , function(){
       var getVal = $(this).val();    //get the selected value
       $.each(_cities , function(i){   //loop through the _cities 
          if(_cities[i].countryID == getVal){  // if the country id equal the selected value
            $("#cities").html('<option value="'+_cities[i].id+'">'+_cities[i].City+'</option>'); // use html( here to change all the cities select with the new cities list
           }
        });
    }).change();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="countries"></select>
<select id="cities"></select>
```

**Note:** Don't forget to change `_citeis` to `_cities`